# Laragon fatal error when access to localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: windows, fatal-error, laragon

I have a freshly installed laragon and it's giving me an error when I'm accessing localhost/phpmyadmin/

```
Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in C:\laragon\etc\apps\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\DatabaseInterface.php on line 615
```

I tried first to install it with the quick installer and then manually after deleting the old phpMyAdmin folder in C:\laragon\etc\apps. I still have the same message.
I downloaded the last version of phpMyAdmin directly on their website and unzip it following the thousands of web's tutos...

Config :

- Windows 10 pro 21H2
- Laragon 5.0.0 210523
- PHP 8.1.10
- Apache 2.4.47
- MySQL 5.7.33

Please, does someone could help me to fix this issue ? :)

Thanks !